# Backbone + JQuery Plugin won't work (Written in CoffeeScript)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, coffeescript

Ok, I have a simple JQuery plugin that when applied to a div will neatly load all the images within that div using a preloader image. This works fine.

However, in Backbone i'm appending data from JSON to a  element after the page has been loaded. Therefore the code below won't work.

```
$(document).ready( ->
    $("#theList").preloader()
)
```

So I need to put the "$("#theList").preloader()" in my render function, after my list is generated..

```
class HomeView extends Backbone.View
constructor: ->
    super

initialize: ->
    @isLoading = false

events: {
     "click #nextPage": "nextPage"
     "click #prevPage": "prevPage"  
}


template: _.template($('#home').html())
theListTemplate: _.template($('#theList').html())

render: ->
    $(@el).append(@template)
    @loadResults()
    $("#theList").preloader() #<----------------- DOESN'T WORK NOW


loadResults: () ->
    @isLoading = true

    Properties.fetch({
        success: (data) =>

            #Append properties to list
            $('#theList').append(@theListTemplate({data: data.models, _:_})).listview('refresh')


        error: ->
            @isLoading = false
            alert('Unable to load information')
    })
```

However, now the line of code is within a Backbone View/Model/Controller or whatever, it doesn't work..

For reference I load my application like so..

```
$(document).ready( ->
    console.log('document ready')
    app.AppRouter = new AppRouter()
    Backbone.history.start()
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the preloader isn't intended to operate on the nodes added in the `loadResults#fetch#success` (since the fetch has not returned by the time you invoke the preloader), I suspect the issue is that, during the execution of the `render()` function, the view's `el` is not part of the DOM yet.

If you invoke `HomeView` like

```
myHomeView = new HomeView()
$('some selector').append(myHomeView.render().el)
```

the HomeView's el has not yet been added to the DOM, its in a detached document.

Therefore the jQuery selector `$("#theList")` returns an empty result - since its searching the DOM.  This is easily verified by either console.log'n the result of that selector, or putting a breakpoint in using a debugger, and testing using the console.

Thankfully, the fix is easy.  You need to reference the detached document by scoping the selector to the view, either using the [jQuery reference scoped to the view](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar):

```
@$("#theList").preloader()
```

or, by doing it yourself

```
$(@el).find("#theList").preloader()
```

Comment: doh!  Yep.  Fixed.  Thanks for spotting that.